# Numbering a certain word in a text

Tags: python, string, text, python-re

I want to provide a reference number as (number) format to certain words in text.

I do get some correct output by using the code below. However when there are same words with adjectives or when the word has appendix it doesnt work.

All of the edge cases I could think of are these two, when there are same words including adjectives and then being able to match the word in dictionary if a word gets appendix in the text.

tried this,

```
import re

text = "This is a first sample and this is a second sample."
words_to_number = {"first sample": 1, "second sample": 2, "sample": 3}

for keyword, number in words_to_number.items():
    pattern = r"\b"+keyword+r"\b"
    text = re.sub(pattern, keyword+" ("+str(number)+")", text)

print(text)
```

got this,
**This is a first sample (3) (1) and this is a second sample (3) (2).**

instead of,
**This is a first sample (1) and this is a second sample (2).**

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that you are putting the keyword back in after matching it, so subsequent keywords which are (possibly) prefixes of a keyword can still be matched.

Consider what happens when you don't put the matched keyword back:

```
import re

text = "This is a first sample and this is a second sample."
words_to_number = {"first sample": 1, "second sample": 2, "sample": 3}

for keyword, number in words_to_number.items():
    pattern = rf"\b{keyword}\b"
    text = re.sub(pattern, f"({number})", text)

print(text)  # This is a (1) and this is a (2).
```

To fix the issue, you could use the number as a placeholder and put each keyword back in a second for loop:

```
import re

text = "This is a first sample and this is a second sample."
words_to_number = {"first sample": 1, "second sample": 2, "sample": 3}

for keyword, number in words_to_number.items():
    pattern = rf"\b{keyword}\b"
    text = re.sub(pattern, f"({number})", text)

print(text)  # This is a (1) and this is a (2).

for keyword, number in words_to_number.items():
    pattern = rf"\({number}\)"
    text = re.sub(pattern, f"{keyword} ({number})", text)

print(text)  # This is a first sample (1) and this is a second sample (2).
```

Answer (score 1):

As a single statement, make a single regex using `|` to separate the different regexs and use the *callback* option of `re.sub`.

```
import re

text = "This is a first sample and this is a second sample."
words_to_number = {"first sample": 1, "second sample": 2, "sample": 3}


regex = r"|".join("({})".format(k) for k in words_to_number)

text_new = re.sub(regex, lambda m: r"{} ({})".format(
                    m.group(), words_to_number[m.group()]) , text)

print(text_new)
```

Comment: This is a very late reply, I tried regex and it almost works fine, however in Turkish, there are a lot of words that get appendices. For instance, words_to_number = {"Dişli Kutusu": 1 } dişli kutusu can be dişli kutusunun or dişli kutuları etc., the code above perfectly matches "dişli kutusu" however in aforementioned situations output becomes: dişli kutusu (1) nun, or dişli kutusu (1) ları, how can I solve this?

Comment: maybe you are looking for  _look-around assertions_, [doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax) (the stuffs with `(?...)`)

Answer (score 0):

I would personally drop regex altogether and use Fractalism's method as such:

```py
text = "This is a first sample and this is a second sample."
words_to_number = {"first sample": 1, "second sample": 2, "sample": 3}

for word, number in words_to_number.items():
    text = text.replace(word, str(number))

for word, number in words_to_number.items():
    text = text.replace(str(number), f"{word} ({number})")
```

Regex seems overkill in this situation as you are only matching against predefined strings without additional patterns.

Comment: This is a very late reply, I tried regex and it almost works fine, however in Turkish, there are a lot of words that get appendices. For instance, words_to_number = {"Dişli Kutusu": 1 } dişli kutusu can be dişli kutusunun or dişli kutuları etc., the code above perfectly matches "dişli kutusu" however in aforementioned situations output becomes: dişli kutusu (1) nun, or dişli kutusu (1) ları, how can I solve this?

Comment: The easiest way would be to have those multiple appendices as different keys in your dictionary.

Comment: in turkish that might not be the easiest :) thank you for the answer!

Comment: You could also try a method that instead of replacing the number with the word and number, you look for an adjacent string terminated with a whitespace and include that. Probably a tad more involved and I think regex would come in handy, but you'll figure it out.